Can we stop Guard to proceed until api loads data in Angular
I have applied guard to route, before guard return true/false, I want to load sidebar menu from api. It loads and works perfectly but when I refresh the page guard proceeds as false and did not wait for api to loads data.
Here is my code.
app-routing file
{
    path: '',
    component: BaseLayoutComponent,
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    children:[
        { 
            path: 'main' ,
            resolve:{ menu: MenuResolver },
            loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule),
            canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        },
    ]
},

main-routing file
{
    path: '', 
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'user',
            loadChildren: () => import('./users-management/users-management.module').then(m => m.UsersManagementModule),
            canActivate: [MainGuard],
        },
    ]
} 

MenuResolver will call DropdownUtils class to load data from api.
MenuResolver
export class MenuResolver implements Resolve<any> {

constructor(private dropDownUtils: DropDownUtils) {}

resolve(): Observable<any> {
    return this.dropDownUtils.updatePermission();
}
}

DropdownUtils class
export class DropDownUtils {
protected permissionsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
public permissions$: Observable<any> = this.permissionsSubject.asObservable();
currentUrl: any;

constructor(private menuService: MenuService, private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.fetchPermissions().subscribe();
    });
}

public updatePermission(): Observable<any> {
    return this.fetchPermissions();
}

private fetchPermissions(): Observable<any> {
    return this.menuService.getUserMenu().pipe(
        tap((data: any) => {
            this.extractPermissions(data.data);
        })
    );
}

private extractPermissions(menu: any[]): void {
    const checkPermissions: any[] = [];
    console.log(this.router.url)
    if (menu.length > 0) {
        menu.forEach(element => {
            const screen = element.screens.find((x: any) => x.url === this.router.url);
            if (screen) {
                checkPermissions.push(screen);
            }
        });
    }

    if (checkPermissions.length > 0) {
        const permissions = {
            is_create: checkPermissions.some(item => item.is_create),
            is_delete: checkPermissions.some(item => item.is_delete),
            is_read: checkPermissions.some(item => item.is_read),
            is_update: checkPermissions.some(item => item.is_update)
        };
        this.permissionsSubject.next(permissions);
    }
}
}

canActivate Guard in MainGuard
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('Guard is activated');
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    const token = TokenHelper.getAccessToken();
    if (!token) {
        console.log('Token is missing or expired');
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return of(false);
    }

    if (this.jwtService.isTokenExpired(token)) {
        console.log('Token is expired.');
        this.authService.logout();
        return of(false);
    }

    return this.menu.resolve().pipe(
        switchMap(() => {
            console.log('Menu is resolved');
            return this.dropDownUtils.updatePermission().pipe(
                switchMap(() => this.dropDownUtils.permissions$),
                map((data: any) => {
                    console.log('Permissions data received', data);
                    const hasPermission = data.is_create || data.is_delete || data.is_read || data.is_update;
                    if (hasPermission) {
                        console.log('User has at least one required permission:', hasPermission);
                        return true;
                    }
                    console.log('User lacks the necessary permissions');
                    this.router.navigate(['403']);
                    return false;
                }),
                catchError(error => {
                    console.error('Error in permissions pipeline:', error);
                    this.router.navigate(['403']);
                    return of(false);
                })
            );
        }),
        catchError(error => {
            console.error('Error resolving menu:', error);
            this.router.navigate(['403']);
            return of(false);
        })
    );
}

in user component this is how i am getting latest permissions from dropdownUtils class
ngOnInit() {
    this.dropdownUtils.permissions$
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        finalize(() => {})
    )
    .subscribe((permissions:any) => {
        this.permission = permissions;
        console.log(this.permission)
        this.loadData(this.currentPage, this.rowsPerPage);
    });
}

When I refresh page before dropdown utils class loads data,  main guard proceeds as false because initial value is empty object in dropdownutils.
My question is Am I doing it correctly? Can we fix the issue? Or I should use NgRx over Rxjs ?

you can use rxjs skipor filter to not take in account the empty value perhaps

Try using concatMap rather than switchMap

Ok, i will try both.

Another question is why sidebar menu api os calling 3 times, 1 from app routing, then main routing, then dropdownutils, how i cam prevent that ?
